# Safely uninstalling GStreamer from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: gstreamer

I was going to remove the GStreamer app from my Ubuntu environment with these commands:

sudo apt-get remove *gstreamer*
sudo apt-get purge  *gstreamer*

When I entered the first line I noticed it said it was going to install something:

Terminal output:

The following NEW packages will be installed:
policykit-1-gnome
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 112 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 240 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n

What is this policykit-1-gnome and is it safe to proceed?

thanks...

Comment: You should be more concerned about "112 to remove"

Comment: Is that saying it wants to remove 112 packages? 240 MB seems rather large for just removing this one app. What is the correct way to go about investigating this? I will leave it alone if there is a chance it will corrupt or render useless my OS.

Comment: Start investigating with `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`. DON'T agree to any removal; abort the upgrade instead if necessary. Copy the `upgrade` output and read it line by line. Review the proposed removals and look for patterns.

Comment: @user535733     The sudo apt update & upgrade output did not reveal much: 
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: It reveals that your system is apparently not broken. A good starting point.